# format JSON oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle

i have data in JSON format, I am trying to push it into tables but when the length of JSON is greater than 4000 column services results in null -

```
 SELECt /*+ no_merge */  id,services
FROM json_table( (select data FROM   json_stage), '$[*]'
 COLUMNS ( 
 ID PATH '$.id'   ,
 services varhcar2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.services'))
```

I also tried to use CLOB in place of varchar2(4000) but it results in error -
ORA-40484: invalid data type for JSON_TABLE column

```
 SELECt /*+ no_merge */  id,services
FROM json_table( (select data FROM   json_stage), '$[*]'
 COLUMNS ( 
 ID PATH '$.id'   ,
 services clob  FORMAT JSON PATH '$.services'))
```

What can be the workaround on this?